# LG G2 is not showing up in ADB even if I check USB debugging

Tags: adb

I can't find my device in ADB for my LG G2 phone running Android 4.2 ICS. I have enabled USB debugging.

What did I miss?

Comment: Could be, but that requires some more details: where are you looking for it (Windows, Linux, Mac)? What exact steps have you performed? If Windows, have you installed the appropriate drivers?

Comment: what OS are you trying this on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure "USB Debugging" option checked and your driver has been installed properly.

You can try following step command:
1. adb kill-server
2. adb start-server
3. adb devices

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

On What OS?

For linux try `lsusb` to see if something is listed that could match your phone.

Is the debug icon showing in the notification bar on the phone?